# STS hanging when I open a project

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

When I open a Maven project A, the STS hangs.
I have to kill the thread every time and restart the STS.
If I open the project A before other performs in the STS, everything will be ok.
I am using STS 3.4.0.RELEASE.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Two options**
 1. Open up a STS.ini which will be located in \home\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.2.RELEASE
and this parameter -STS -clean as shown in the below figure.
[image: STS Clean]
 2. Also, from the command prompt, use this parameter to start 
\home\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.2.RELEASE> STS.exe -clean

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the same error, STS hanged always when I tried to open closed project, always on 'Populating detected configs'. What helped me was disabling project builders/validators in Spring options in preferences.